# Limit of $\sqrt x \sin(1/x)$ where $x$ approaches positive infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have a problem as in the title. I cannot use the typical squeeze theorem strick with $-1<\sin(1/x)<1$ since that does not seem to yield anything useful. I also saw a solution that at small values $0<\sin(\theta)<\theta$ but i would like to avoid that since I have not prove that fact really. I was wondering if I could do the following thing:

> We assume that the limit does exist: $\lim \sqrt x \sin(1/x)=L$. Then we square it.
>   $\lim x\sin^2(1/x)=L^2$ and use $u=1/x$ substitution to solve it. My only problem is, i am assuming the limit exists, which i cannot do, so i was wondering if there is a way to fix my proof, or if there is an alternative one that is a nice solution.

Comment: $$0 \, \le \,\sqrt x \sin\dfrac 1 x \, \le \, \sqrt x \cdot \dfrac 1 x \, = \, \dfrac 1 {\sqrt x} \to 0 \text{ as } x\to\infty. $$ (One has $0 \, \le \, \sin(1/x)$ if $x$ is big enough, and what happens for small values of $x$ is of no concern when taking a limit as  $x\to\infty.$) $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\cdot\sqrt{x}\right)=0.$$

Comment: Oh wow, I am surprised I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin\dfrac1x\sim_\infty\dfrac1x,\;\text{so}\quad\sqrt x\sin\dfrac1x\sim_\infty\frac{\sqrt x}x=\frac1{\sqrt x}\to 0.$$

Comment: Doing this by squeezing seems simpler than this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Could be related to how things are usually taught. In France, equivalents are heavily used in "classes préparatoires" and more generally at university level. To me, this is the most natural answer, and the first that comes to mind, by far.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut : It is the first thing that occurred to me as well, but I think one should make things appear as simple as they really are.

Comment: Equivalence is precisely a way to make things simpler: only the relevant features of the situation are retained.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $|\sin a)|\le |a|$ we have

$$\left| \sqrt{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\to 0~~~~as~~~x\to \infty$$

Indeed, 
$$ |\sin a)| =\left|\int_0^a\cos(t)dt\right|\le |a|$$

Answer (score 1):

write $$\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$